# What is the size of bool? 1 bit or 1 byte?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, boolean

```
printf("bool: %zu; true: %zu; 1: %zu\n", sizeof (bool), sizeof true, sizeof 1);
```

The above piece of code yields

```
bool: 1; true: 1; 1: 4
```

I am fine with the sizeof(1), it is an integer and hence 4 bytes size.
But `bool (and true)` only needs a size of `1 "bit"`, still the output is 1 i.e. 1 byte.

Why is this so?

Comment: You need to post source codes, with generated output/behavior & your expected behavior for both cases, specifically mentioning your target environment.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to speak about system limits, without a specific system in mind. The limits you mention are not in the C standard.

Comment: "it actually is of 1 bit only." No? And "sizeof(...)" returns a *byte* number, not bit.

Comment: From C++11 3.9/4 "Types": "The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals sizeof(T)".  The smallest that any type in C++ can be is 1 `char`.

Comment: `printf("boolean: %zu; true: %zu; 1: %zu\n", sizeof (boolean), sizeof true, sizeof 1);`

Comment: sizeof(bool) = 1 sizeof(true) = 1 where I expect it to have 1/8 or 0.125 because bool value takes only one bit. 
The output of sizeof() is in bytes and hence output above shows that they are taking 1 byte and not one bit.

Comment: And this question has very less to do with platform. These are general things . Or even if this is platform dependent, I have given my expectations quiet clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an efficient (packed) representation use [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

```
#include <bitset>

std::bitset<2000000> my_bits;
```

Obviously this is for C++ only. In C you would have to implement this explicitly yourself, e.g.:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

uint8_t my_bits[2000000 / CHAR_BIT];
```

and then to access individual bits you would need to implement some simple inline functions using bitwise operations.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum addressable unit is byte. Each object shall have its address. Also sizeof operator returns number of bytes occupied by an object. Even empty structures in C++ shall have non-zero sizes.

You can use standard class `std::bitset` instead of a boolean array.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to compile sized `std::bitset<N>` is to use the specialization `std::vector<bool>` which has a dynamic size. But **care**, it doesn't act as regular container as it provides [proxy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/reference/) to access individual bit.